# assigning input value to variable

Tags: javascript, json, variables, input, assign

I am trying to assign an input value to a variable that i have retrieved using JSON / PHP from a database. Every time I go to output it I get a blank/null value.

I have created the global variable at the top of the javascript file:

```
 var theAge=0;


 function startApplication(){
    getData();
    getAge();
    alert(theAge);
 }



 function getData(){
 $.getJSON('http://www.myphpfile.co.uk/myfile.php', function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                            $("#userAge").val(val.age);  
                    });
            });
 }



 function getAge(){
    theAge = document.getElementById('#userAge').value;
 }
```

So i am creating the variable theAge, grabbing the data from the database and displaying it in an input field, then trying to grab the input value with the getAge function  to then alert it to check its worked. Im just getting a blank box. Can anyone see any errors? Thanks.

Comment: `document.getElementById('#userAge')` remove the hashtag.

Comment: Or, if you want to use jQuery `$("#userAge").val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is an asynchronous call to a remote url, which means the script continues on past that line while a response is being fetched.

By the time your script gets to `getAge();` and `alert(theAge);`, the response has not yet returned, so `theAge` is still 0.

Whatever you want to do with the value you get from the remote call needs to be passed in as a callback function. You're already passing a function in there (`function(data) { $.each...`)  -- the rest of what you need to have done with that response (for example, `getAge()` and alerting the value) needs to be handled in there as well.

**update**

Assign the value and alert it inside the callback:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.myphpfile.co.uk/myfile.php', function(data) {
     $.each(data, function(key, val) {
         $("#userAge").val(val.age);  
     });
     theAge = document.getElementById('userAge').value;
     alert(theAge);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would you suggest i assign the value of userAge from the call to the global variable theAge? Apologies i've not been doing Javascript very long.

Comment: This is good, but the hash tag should be removed from the `getElementById` call.  Or simply do `$('#userAge').val()`.